# Error al intentar instalar extensiones en jupyter lab 2.2.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Intento hacer una transición de jupyter a jupyter lab2.0. He instalado el paquete en un entorno nuevo. Al intentar instalar algunas de las extensiones que vienen por defecto en el paquete, siempre me da el error

```
"@jupyterlab/translation" is not a valid npm package
```

El error se reproduce con cualquiera de las extensiones que vienen por defecto.

Tengo instalado: `python 3.8.5`, JupyterLab v2.2.6
y `nodejs 10.13.0`

Por otro lado, ¿Cómo se puede actualizar a jupyter lab 3?. La opción indicada por jupyterlab,   `conda conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`
me ha instalado la versión 2.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa? ¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?. Agradecere ayuda.

Comment: Hola efueyo! Entiendo que si instalas la versión, tres de jupyterlab, el error puede que desaparezca. En todo caso creo que sería bueno siguiendo [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que publiques una pregunta por problema, quiero decir, **actualizar Jupyter** e instalar una extensión "X" no está relacionado, y creo que deberían ser preguntas distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre que quieras instalar una versión específica de cualquier paquete, tanto con `pip` como con `conda` puedes usar la síntaxis `=<version_paquete>` al final de la instalación. En tu caso **con Anaconda** sería:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3
```

**Con pip**:

```
pip install jupyterlab=3
```

Si quieres ser más concreto puedes especificar más la versión o incluso los parches, por ejemplo aquí instalamos el primer parche `3.0.1`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que no había finalizado todos los pasos para la instalación correcta de **nodejs** y **npm**. Faltaba ejecutar las dos sentencias siguientes.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
jlpm config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com/
```